# Law of Demeter violation search tool?

Tags: c#, law-of-demeter, code-standards

Does anybody know of a tool that I could use with a C# application to find possible Law of Demeter violations? I know that it would give a lot of false positives, but I think it could still be useful. Especially during the early design process.

Comment: wiki definition of Law of Demeter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: *The law of Demeter* should be *The rule of thumb of Demeter* imho . . .

Comment: I don't know of any such tools, but a good approach to one in .NET would be to base it on reflection and IL so that it could work for any .NET language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for `something.somethingelse.violation`, then you can use Visual Studio.

In the find dialog, check the box at the bottom to "Use" and select "Regular Expressions."

Not very robust, but you can use `<[:a_]+\.([:a_]+\.)+[:a_]+` to find the pattern above.

A better tool would be `grep` or similar on the solution directory, so you can use more powerful regex options like negative lookbehind, which would allow you to exclude things like `using` directives and `namespace` declarations.

[grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

You could probably very quickly write a .NET app that would recurse a given directory and search .cs and/or .vb files for same, using .NET Regex, which has lookarounds, but of course the advantage of using VS is that you remain right in the source code editor.

Comment: Hmm, I just found 5 'dots' in my program... according to [six degrees of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation), I think that means it can access anything in my program right? :P