# Find LoD violation in VS2022 using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2022

This question is based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460418/law-of-demeter-violation-search-tool) that is closed because it asks for a recommendation of a tool.

In Visual Studio 2022, using the Find in Files dialog *(CTRL + SHIFT + F)* how can I find matches for the following. First I will list the input samples then the expected matches. In the following text, `a`, `b` and `c` are single-word tokens in ASCII encoding.

```
this->a->b->c;
this->a.b.c;
this->a.b->c;
this->a->b.c;
this->a;
```

Matches.

```
a->b->c
a.b.c
a.b->c
a->b.c
NO MATCH
```

In other words I want to find violations of Law of Demeter. The `this` and `;` token should NOT be a part of the match. If an instance of a class accesses its direct field it shouldn't access any fields of that field.

What have I tried?

```
\((\b(?!this\b)[\s\S]*?)\)
([\s\S]*?)(this)
this(.|->)(.*(.|->).*(.|->).*)
```

The regex dialect is the one that C# uses because that's what Visual Studio uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To matches described in question you could use this:

```
(?<=this->)\w+(?:->|\.)\w+(?:->|\.)\w+(?=;)
```

**Edit:** corrected regex to match something like this `this->a->b()->c(x, y);`:

```
(?<=this->)[\w(), ]+(?:->|\.)[\w(), ]+(?:->|\.)[\w(), ]+(?=;)
```

- `(?<=this->)` - searches for `this->` before your match,
- `[\w(), ]+(?:->|\.)[\w(), ]+(?:->|\.)[\w(), ]+` - described pattern to match,
- `(?=;)` - checks, that immediately after pattern there is a semicolon.

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KPYOOT/1)

Comment: I tried it in VS2022 and it didn't match `this->a->b()->c(x, y);`. However, this should match because it's similar to the rule `this->a->b->c;` where `b = b()` and `c = c(x, y)`.

Comment: @sanitizedUser, `\w` matches only word symbols: letters, numbers and `_`. For regex to match other symbols you need to expand expression. I edited answer to reflex your new example, and added link to regex101, where you can test matches.

Comment: Good edit. There are of course some false positives because the closure parentheses isn't checked but that's OK.